# Lean4 Exercise: Double negation implies law of excluded middle

Tags: lean4

Been trying to do this exercise from Section 3 of the tutorial for hours and I cannot get it to check. Here's my best attempt below (theorem dne provided by the book):

```
variable (p : Prop)

open Classical

theorem dne (h : ¬¬p) : p :=
  Or.elim (em p)
  (fun (hp : p) => hp)
  (fun (hnp: ¬p) => absurd hnp h)

theorem step (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬ p)) : ¬p :=
  fun (hp : p) => h (Or.intro_left (¬p) (hp))

theorem exclmid : p ∨ ¬p :=
  dne (
    fun (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬p)) => 
    h (Or.intro_right (p) (step h))
  )
```

When I type-check my 'step' lemma, I get that it says "∀ (p : Prop), ¬(p ∨ ¬p) → ¬p". I thought that I can give 'step' something of type ¬(p ∨ ¬p) and it will return something of type ¬p, but when I check it on specific examples it doesn't do that.

I've tried a lot of other attempts but I don't get helpful feedback from the editor, so I'm not sure where it's going wrong (like below).

```
theorem excmid : p ∨ ¬p :=
  dne (
    fun (h : ¬ (p ∨ ¬p)) : False => 
    fun (h2 : p ∨ ¬p) : False =>
    have np : ¬p := fun (hp : p) => h2 (Or.intro_left (¬p) (hp))
    h h2 (Or.intro_right p np)
  )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first argument of your step is a prop p. The second argument is your h.  Lean 4 has a fancy feature where you don’t have to make (p : Prop) explicit in the definition.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does that mean there's a hidden input to step that is being eaten at step h instead of the thing I intend?

Comment: I don't know what your exercise actually was.  But if it was to prove `p ∨ ¬p` in Lean, note, this is already there as `em p`, which you are using to prove `dne`.

Comment: @JasonRute, the exercise is here: https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/propositions_and_proofs.html#classical-logic and the wording is "As an exercise, you might try proving the converse, that is, showing that em can be proved from dne."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: Supply the argument `p ∨ ¬ p` to both `dne` and `p` to `step`, or use implicit arguments.

---

You are almost there!

### The `variable` command

The `variable (p : Prop)` command can be a bit confusing.  At first it looks like it is saying "for this whole section, just fix `p` to be a `Prop`", but the problem is what do you do with definitions and theorems which use this `p`?  How do you use them inside this section (when `variable (p : Prop)` is in scope) and how do you use them outside this section (when `variable (p : Prop)` is no longer in scope!)?  Lean simplifies this (compared to say Coq modules) and instead `variable (p : Prop)` actually just means "for this whole section, any theorem or definition which uses `p` gets `(p : Prop)` automatically added to its assumptions in the signature".  When you use the theorem you have to supply a value for this `p` argument.

To make it more clear, here are four solutions (with an interlude on solving term proofs in Lean):

### Solution 1

Instead of `variable (p : Prop)` we can just write `(p : Prop)` explicitly:

```
open Classical

theorem dne (p : Prop) (h : ¬¬p) : p :=
  Or.elim (em p)
  (fun (hp : p) => hp)
  (fun (hnp: ¬p) => absurd hnp h)

theorem step (p : Prop) (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬ p)) : ¬p :=
  fun (hp : p) => h (Or.intro_left (¬p) (hp))

theorem exclmid (p : Prop) : p ∨ ¬p :=
  dne (p ∨ ¬p) (
    fun (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬p)) => 
    h (Or.intro_right (p) (step p h))
  )
```

Here we supply the proposition `p ∨ ¬p` to `dne` and `p` to `step` as the first argument.

### Solution 2

In your MWE, we have `variable (p : Prop)`.  Nonetheless, we still have to explicitly supply that argument to both `dne` and `step`:

```
variable (p : Prop)

open Classical

theorem dne (h : ¬¬p) : p :=
  Or.elim (em p)
  (fun (hp : p) => hp)
  (fun (hnp: ¬p) => absurd hnp h)

theorem step (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬ p)) : ¬p :=
  fun (hp : p) => h (Or.intro_left (¬p) (hp))

theorem exclmid : p ∨ ¬p :=
  dne (p ∨ ¬p) (
    fun (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬p)) => 
    h (Or.intro_right (p) (step p h))
  )
```

### Lean errors

Note, if you don't supply the `p` argument to `step`, then Lean does give fairly helpful errors
(but of course error messages can always be improved!).

```
application type mismatch
  step h
argument
  h
has type
  ¬(p ∨ ¬p) : Prop
but is expected to have type
  Prop : Type
```

This is saying that your first argument to `step` is wrong.  You should be putting a `Prop` in the first argument slot, not a proof of `¬(p ∨ ¬p)`.  When you print `step`, you get:

```
theorem step : ∀ (p : Prop), ¬(p ∨ ¬p) → ¬p :=
fun p h hp => h (Or.intro_left (¬p) hp)
```

You see the first argument comes from `∀ (p : Prop)`.

### Using holes (`_`) to solve term proofs

Here is some advice to solving term proofs in Lean.  The most helpful tool in making term proofs is holes, i.e. the underscore character.  (Note, tactic proofs, which you will cover later are even easier!) You correctly noticed that your proof needs to start with `dne`.  So we start with the template:

```
theorem exclmid : p ∨ ¬p :=
  dne _ _
```

Why two underscores?  Zero, one, and three underscores give an error at `dne`, while two underscores only puts the error at the underscore, so we know that is the correct number of arguments to `dne`.  Next, we hover over the two underscores.  The first, says:

```
p: Prop
⊢ Prop
```

The second says:

```
p: Prop
⊢ ¬¬(p ∨ ¬p)
```

So the first must be a `Prop` and the second a proof of `¬¬(p ∨ ¬p)`.  But these are not independent.  The `Prop` in the first actually is linked to the proof in the second.  So the only possible value for the first is `p ∨ ¬p`.  Lean therefore automatically puts the `p ∨ ¬p` in for you when you do the first `_`.

A good way to solve a term proof is just to use this trick over and over again until you solved the theorem.  So next you can start to fill the proof of `¬¬(p ∨ ¬p)` in by replacing the second underscore with `(fun h => _)`.  Again, Lean will tell you both the type of `h` and the expected type of the new hole.

### Solution 3: Implicit arguments

Notice that Lean is smart enough to know that the first argument to `dne` is `p ∨ ¬p` and to `step` is `p`.  So one could have just written, say, `step _ h` in the examples above.  Better however, would be to mark `(p : Prop)` as implicit in the theorems themselves.  This can be done with either `variable {p : Prop}` or `theorem step {p : Prop} (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬ p)) : ¬p`.  Now we don't have to supply that annoying first argument and the proof you wrote goes through as is!

```
variable {p : Prop}

open Classical

theorem dne (h : ¬¬p) : p :=
  Or.elim (em p)
  (fun (hp : p) => hp)
  (fun (hnp: ¬p) => absurd hnp h)

theorem step (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬ p)) : ¬p :=
  fun (hp : p) => h (Or.intro_left (¬p) (hp))

theorem exclmid : p ∨ ¬p :=
  dne (
    fun (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬p)) => 
    h (Or.intro_right (p) (step h))
  )
```

### Solution 4: Lean 4 magic

Finally, Lean 4 offers a bit of magic.  If a variable like `p` in a definition or theorem, is just one symbol and its type (`Prop` in this case) can be inferred from the rest of the theorem, then it is automatically added as an implicit argument to the theorem signature. In this case `{p : Prop}` is added automatically to the theorem signature.  That means all we have to do is take your MWE and remove the `variable` line!

```
open Classical

theorem dne (h : ¬¬p) : p :=
  Or.elim (em p)
  (fun (hp : p) => hp)
  (fun (hnp: ¬p) => absurd hnp h)

theorem step (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬ p)) : ¬p :=
  fun (hp : p) => h (Or.intro_left (¬p) (hp))

theorem exclmid : p ∨ ¬p :=
  dne (
    fun (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬p)) => 
    h (Or.intro_right (p) (step h))
  )
```

Magic!

Comment: Thanks! That was a lot of really useful information. One small correction I think is that in your first two solutions it should say `dne (p ∨ ¬p) ( ... )` in theorem exclmid. Very nicely Lean figures that out itself in the implicit examples. Cheers!

Comment: @TFS19 Thanks.  (I thought I tested all this. :/)  Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

[Jason Rute](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/122/jason-rute)'s [answer](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/posts/1857) is really good. I rewrite it to make it more compact and clear.

1. remove the `open classical` and `theorem dne` to avoid to prove an axiom.
2. embed the `next` to rewrite the proof into an example.

```
example (dne : {p : Prop} -> (¬¬p -> p)): p ∨ ¬p :=
  dne (
    fun (h : ¬(p ∨ ¬p)) => 
    h (
      Or.inr (
        fun hp: p => h (Or.inl hp)
      )
    ) 
  )
```